# BLE app problem with Android Studio 3.3.2

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

BLE app problem with Android Studio 3.3.2

I have a simple Bluetooth LE Explorer program I used to compile using Android Studio. That app worked properly with previous Android Studio versions. 
I just updated Android Studio to version 3.3.2, I compiled it after having to update the build.gradle, but then the app no longer sees any Bluetooth device when scanning. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you add GPS permission in AndroidManifest.xml?
Something like

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Since Android API 18(?) BLE need GPS permission.

Because some device (ex: iBeacon) need location.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I added that line in AndroidManifest.xml but it didn't work.

Comment: Now I remember during the update I had to remove this line:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />

When I had that line it says 'Permission is only granted to system apps', so I had to remove it in order to compile. So I think the question is how to enable that permission.

Comment: @vn2000 
 Here are all I have in my AndroidManifest.xml    

1. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

2. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
3. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
My application work well~

Comment: Also, you need to turn on the GPS permission for you app in setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following statements in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

But the BLE apps still cannot see any BLE device. I'm not sure what else could be missing.